# Iterative filtering odd numbers in list

Tags: list, filter, numbers, scheme, iteration

Here is a task I have to solve: Write an iterative function, that receives a list with numbers and creates a new list, which only consists of the even numbers from the received list.

I even found a few posts with similar questions and solutions, but I couldn't use them as help, because in these solution they were using the "car" and "cdr" commands, which we haven't had in our schedule yet. How can  do this?  I would start like this:

```
(define filter-odds
  (lambda(x)
    (if (odd? x)
      ...)
```

Comment: So what part of Scheme have you seen? Did you see `first` and `rest`, for example?

Comment: Sure I have seen `first` and `rest`... but even with these two commands I wasnt able to solve the task.

Comment: Well then use whatever solution you found and liked, and simply substitute `car` with `first` and `cdr` with `rest`, because they are the same thing (for proper lists).

Comment: Write a "regular" recursive version first, to ensure that your logic is sound. Then make it iterative (tail recursive) by adding an accumulator parameter. (Since this is homework, you're probably expected to do the recursion "manually" and not delegate it to a reduction function.) If you need a good book, SICP is [available online](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and explains this rather well.

Comment: @uselpa: Thanks for your answers. Maybe I should have mentioned that me and my class are total beginners. It was seriously not my intention to ask stupid questions for not knowing that `first` and `car` or `rest` and `crd` are the same.

Comment: @user5758655 nothing wrong with not knowing stuff; but it is a good SO etiquette to stay online  when  you've asked a question, if possible, to clarify things that others might ask about, in a timely manner. :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, in the absence of `car` ⁄ `cdr` accessors, your only other choice is using `reduce` from [SRFI1](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-1/srfi-1.html#reduce):

```
(define filter-odds
  (lambda (lst)
    (reduce-right
      (lambda (e     ; list's element
               acc)  ; accumulated results from the right
         (if (odd? e)
           ....      ; combine e and the results-so-far
           .... ))   ; ignore e
      '()
      lst )))
```

But, *right* reduce most likely won't be iterative. *Left* reduce usually is. It will build the result in reverse order though, but you can reverse a list iteratively in another pass, using the same approach, without filtering at all (i.e. using the test procedure which always succeeds).

---

With the `first` ⁄ `rest` accessors available though, all you need to do is to write down the implementation for `reduce` yourself, then *fuse* it into the definitions above:

```
(define reduce
   (lambda (f acc ls)
      (if (null? ls)
         acc
         (reduce f (f acc (first ls)) .....))))
```

In other words, just follow the above [code skeleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skeleton_(computer_programming)) and add replace the call to `f` with some checks for `odd?` or something, to get the `filter-odd?-reversed`; then figure out the `f` to use so as to define the `reverse-list` function.

Comment: No, he's allowed to use first (= car) and rest (= cdr)

Answer (score 0):

Terrible oversight: no one has mentioned [How To Design Programs](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/matthias/HtDP2e/), here. This kind of program is right smack in the middle of HtDP's path. Specifically, this is a totally straightforward application of the List template from section 9.3, "Programming with Lists." Perhaps your class is already using HtDP?